# Rails Httpclient 2.7.1 : OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Could not generate secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, httpclient

I am getting error

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Could not generate secret
    from ...../httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/jruby_ssl_socket.rb:504:in `initialize'
    from ..../httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/jruby_ssl_socket.rb:442:in `create_socket'
    from ..../httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:739:in `connect'
```

Is anyone faces same?

Answer (score 1):

From some googling, this seems to be an issue caused by the underlying java implementation which is responsible for the actual crypto when setting up a TLS connection. It seems, most of the time this error occured when trying to setup a TLS connection with elliptic curve keys.

There are a couple of reports with an error description similar to yours which could be fixed by using a newer version of Java, e.g. JRE 8. Also, I found [a report](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/issues/86) where this issue seemed to be connected to OpenJDK which did things slightly different then Oracle Java.

Thus, you should first try to move to a newer version of Oracle Java. If that fails, you might be able to disable elliptic curve crypto and fallback to "old-school" crypto by adding this to your JRuby arguments:

```
jruby -J-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false path/to/script.rb
```

Note however, that it is generally not advisable to turn off elliptic-curve crypto here if you can avoid it. ECC is much faster (and less CPU-intensive on both sides) and is often more secure than the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here debugging options available use and fix the issue

```
require 'openssl'
   OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: That does not fix the issue. If anything, it masks the problem by completely turning off security. That said, as in this case the reason is most probably not certificate validation but a protocol issue with some cipher, it won't even help at all.